# Charles 3.10.1 does not have ssl option to setting?

Tags: charles-proxy

[image]

why charles does not have ssl option?

How can I capture package with https?

Answer (score 6):

You have another tab for ssl connection options.

Go to `tab menu -> Proxy -> SSL Proxy Settings`

There you have the option to enable SSL proxy.